# Echo DISTINCT row to remove duplicate results from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, duplicates

I have the following code, works great:

```php
///////////////////////
$todo=$_POST['todo'];
if(isset($todo) and $todo=="search"){
$species=$_POST['species'];
$lab_section=$_POST['lab_section'];
$search_text=$_POST['search_text'];
$type=$_POST['type'];     

$query="select * from mytable where  ";

if(strlen($species) > 0 ){
$query.= " species='$species' and "; 
}
if(strlen($lab_section) > 0 ){
$query.= " lab_section='$lab_section' and "; 
}

////////////////////////// Key word search query /////////
$search_text=ltrim($search_text);
$search_text=rtrim($search_text);

if(strlen($search_text)>0){ 
    if($type<>"any"){
$query .=" name='$search_text'";
        }else{
$kt=split(" ",$search_text);//Breaking the string to array of words
// Now let us generate the sql 
            while(list($key,$val)=each($kt)){
if($val<>" " and strlen($val) > 0){$query .= " lab_section like '%$val%' or name like '%$val%' or species like '%$val%' or ";}
                }
$query=substr($query,0,(strLen($query)-3));
// this will remove the last or from the string. 
        } // end of if else based on type value
$query.=" and ";
}// end of if area , if search_text value is entered

$query=substr($query,0,(strLen($query)-4));

echo "<div class='search-separator'></div>";
// Display records ////
foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $t) {
echo "$t[name],$t[lab_section],$t[price],$t[species]"; }
} 
?>
```

But MYSQL has rows that are near-duplicates. But they all have unique names. SO I need to remove duplicate results by name. In other words, I just want to list the results by their unique name. How do I remove the duplicate results by their unique name?

I thought I could do it, for instance by this:

```php
select DISTINCT ...... 
from mytable
group by name
```

But I don't know where to put this in my above code....

Comment: so where is your final query?

Comment: Can you provide data samples? Do you have a unique name column? Distinct removes duplicates, not similar ones.

Comment: Try `$query .=" name='$search_text GROUP BY name'";` - But this is the part I don't get `or species like '%$val%' or ";}` with the `or` at the end like that. I can't see the continuation of it.

Comment: chris, that's why I was hoping for a GROUP BY.

Comment: FRED, I don't think the last or has to be there... It was just a code I borrowed that left option for continuing.

That line of code did not return anything different. It still returns the same.

Comment: Did you try `$query .=" name='$search_text GROUP BY name'";`? Or, did you need a seperate statement?

Comment: Yes. Just tried. No difference in results... 
Maybe I should specify above. 

I have one column with 5 different possible combinations. And so when you use the dropdown to select one of the combinations, it is listing all the combinations (because I had to duplicate them in the MYSQL database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type your DISTINCT in line

```
$query="select * from mytable where  ";
```

GROUP you can use after line

```
$query=substr($query,0,(strLen($query)-4));
```

BUT generally, the code is not good.
do not use in queries values passed directly from user ($_GET,$_POST,etc). Use at least sprintf(), but better to use placeholders.

why you cant replace these two lines:
    $search_text=ltrim($search_text);
    $search_text=rtrim($search_text);
with `$search_text=trim($search_text);`

you do not need line `$query=substr($query,0,(strLen($query)-4));` you can write all those query parts to array for example, and then make implode(' AND ',$conditions); just after "while"

Comment: Including "select DISTINCT name, lab_section from mytable where " worked. Let me explore a little more if this did everything it should have. Thank you!